# Override local code block

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I have a module in `app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Price.php`. In this file, theres a function, called `getSliderJs`.

Now I do want to override this method. I've created my own module and created a new file in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Block/Layer/Price.php`.

I extend it with `class Vendor_Module_Block_Layer_Price extends  Smartwave_Ajaxcatalog_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price`.

However, I've activated the module by creating the corresponding XML files, however, it does not extend the desired method.

Do I need to put something else in `config.xml`, or get such blocks autoloaded? Afaik module files get autoloaded by ZF enginge but it seems that I'm completely wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I need to rewrite the Block in my `config.xml`

In `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml` I now have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <filter_price>Vendor_Module_Block_Filter_Price</filter_price>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in your config.xml.
From curent code it looks like you are trying to rewrite app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Filter/Price.php with your custom block file app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Block/Filter/Price.php

Please share config.xml of smartwave module also whose block you want to override so that I can help you in better way.

Comment: Check my answer, tho